# VCFloatingButtonAction error

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-action-button

I am getting these two error in my project after importing VCFloatingActionButton
1.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"OBJC_CLASS$_VCFloatingActionButton", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in CreateServiceWizardViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
2.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If anyone has used this component intheir project, kindly guide me on how to use this component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have used Cocoa pods for VCFloatingButtonAction for intregation, Cocoapods makes a .xcworkspace file after the intregation is complete. If you open you project by normal .xcodeproj file, xcode will not find the framework and give you linker crash.

Open the project with .xcworkspace and not not .xcodeproj file and everything would be fine.